# install material-ui in visual studio react project

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to using npm and react inside Visual Studio. Tried to install Material-UI@next for my React project but got these warnings when running the project.

[image]

```
[at-loader] ./node_modules/material-ui/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.d.ts:12:11 
TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ButtonHTMLAttributes'.
[at-loader] ./node_modules/material-ui/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.d.ts:13:9 
TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'AnchorHTMLAttributes'.
[at-loader] ./node_modules/material-ui/Chip/Chip.d.ts:4:18 
TS2430: Interface 'ChipProps' incorrectly extends interface 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.
Types of property 'label' are incompatible.
Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
[at-loader] ./node_modules/material-ui/Form/FormControl.d.ts:5:17 
TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'HtmlHTMLAttributes'.
[at-loader] ./node_modules/material-ui/Form/FormControlLabel.d.ts:13:11 
TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'LabelHTMLAttributes'.
...
```

[image]

Something obvious I am missing?

Comment: Are you using an AMD module loader (i.e. CommonJS or RequireJS)?...

Comment: No, I don't think so. I am using webpack to pack the js-files. The project is based on the Visual Studio template "React.js and Redux", and the only change I've made so far is adding Material-UI.

Comment: what version of visual studio?

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2017, Version 15.3.5

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue getting the latest Material-UI working with .Net core's 'react/redux' template.  I found it to be a matter of getting the correct versions of the dependencies in order.

In order to get it working, I updated all of the packages to the latest versions:

`$ npm install -g npm-check-updates
 $ npm-check-updates -u
 $ npm install`

Once I updated those refs, some of the sample code broke.  So I simply removed the broken bits as all I cared about was getting Material-UI working.

Once I had that part, I just had to do the proper imports and was able to use the Paper element.

Here is an example of how I got it working.

https://github.com/cbehrends/MaterialUI_DotNetCore.git

Good Luck!

Edit:
I've updated the repo and fixed any version issues I found.  I'm going to try and keep this repo updated as best I can.  Cheers!